# BIOS compatible boot mode is not working as Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode

Tags: boot

After installing Ubundu, I may have unmounted the windows boot partition by mistake and now when I try to reboot, it is not finding any bootable partition and windows 8.1 seems to be gEFI mode to CMS mode, Ubuntu boots fine but It seems that my windows boot sector has been corrupted or I have force the Ubuntu to install in UEFI mode and now windows seems to be lost.

Checking online, I found that I need to create FAT bootable partition and as been a novice in Linux, I will appreciate if someone can give me a step by step instruction to fix this issue. I am copying the text from boot repair suggestion herewith as well.

Appreciate the help.

```
 Boot Info Script cfd9efe + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 26Apr2016]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32800 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

ubuntu-vg-root: ________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

ubuntu-vg-swap_1: ______________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       999,423       997,376  83 Linux
/dev/sda2           1,001,470   976,771,071   975,769,602   5 Extended
/dev/sda5           1,001,472   976,771,071   975,769,600  8e Linux LVM


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 29.9 GiB, 32094814208 bytes, 62685184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048    62,685,183    62,683,136   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 7fd7ad13-019a-4542-81d0-e212800a230d   ext4       
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 f991bcb4-8364-405b-b734-26f8de898b5b   swap       
/dev/sda1        d7a48cac-6e76-44cb-8135-7a49337f4a74   ext2       
/dev/sda5        q3T2lz-jkdR-cSfI-KvST-MeYP-3Pq2-XNvj9r LVM2_member 
/dev/sdb1        0C58-8CDC                              vfat       UBUNTU 16_0

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  3 03:55 ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD050_33J5SNQDS -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD050_33J5SNQDS-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD050_33J5SNQDS-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD050_33J5SNQDS-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  3 03:33 ata-TSSTcorp_CDDVDW_SU-208FB_S11S6YGF801DV1 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-root -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-swap_1 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 dm-uuid-LVM-lvJsyh8lP2dY7Tx8om0ht2YUF1U5r7StCR0gSrBdDuUwXss7Y9HXU1m40CLXrLIf -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 dm-uuid-LVM-lvJsyh8lP2dY7Tx8om0ht2YUF1U5r7StWaqw7RhdMPYvx5lUe7eJDOgk5PRHwRGR -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 lvm-pv-uuid-q3T2lz-jkdR-cSfI-KvST-MeYP-3Pq2-XNvj9r -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  3 03:55 usb-__070A64A4DDAF3E22-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 usb-__070A64A4DDAF3E22-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug  3 03:55 wwn-0x50000394a58036e1 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 wwn-0x50000394a58036e1-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 wwn-0x50000394a58036e1-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug  3 03:55 wwn-0x50000394a58036e1-part5 -> ../../sda5


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

   0.174905777 = 0.187803648    grub/grub.cfg                                  7
   0.174742699 = 0.187628544    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          2
   0.066134453 = 0.071011328    vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic                      10
   0.086462021 = 0.092837888    initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic                   15

=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

========================== ubuntu-vg-root/etc/fstab: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=d7a48cac-6e76-44cb-8135-7a49337f4a74 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=d7a48cac-6e76-44cb-8135-7a49337f4a74  /boot   ext2    defaults    0   2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda2



=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

hexdump: /dev/sda2: No such device or address
hexdump: /dev/sda2: No such device or address
File descriptor 9 (/proc/13133/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 21048: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[88122]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 21048: bash
File descriptor 9 (/proc/13133/mounts) leaked on lvchange invocation. Parent PID 21916: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[88122]) leaked on lvchange invocation. Parent PID 21916: bash
File descriptor 9 (/proc/13133/mounts) leaked on lvchange invocation. Parent PID 21916: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[88122]) leaked on lvchange invocation. Parent PID 21916: bash



Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 976771071 975769602 465.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 976771071 975769600 465.3G 8e Linux LVM




Disk /dev/sdb: 29.9 GiB, 32094814208 bytes, 62685184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x04b28371

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 62685183 62683136 29.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 461.4 GiB, 495414411264 bytes, 967606272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 3.9 GiB, 4177526784 bytes, 8159232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
/boot detected. Please check the options.


=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to enable-raid enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub2 of mapper/ubuntu--vg-root into the MBR of sda, using the following options:        sda1/boot,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


=================== Advice in case of suggested repair
The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Do you want to continue?


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.
```

Answer (score 0):

Boot Info found no Windows partition, what doesn't exist cannot be booted. If you need Windows you have to install it again. Laptop manufacturers offer their own reinstall media for Windows these days, but you can also get them directly from Microsoft, as I described [here](https://superuser.com/a/900235/252532). This would have been even better if you had taken Microsoft's free upgrade offer to Windows 10. Apparently you didn't (too much media hysteria?), now you're stuck with a dead product.

Boot Info found a dos/MBR partition layout, an LVM installation of Ubuntu in an extended partition, no EFI system partition and it says your boot loader loads /grub/i386-pc/core.img. If this boots successfully then you're not booting UEFI.

Since reinstalling is almost inevitable from my point of view here are some tips to make your life easier:

1. If your computer supports UEFI and you want to boot operating systems this way, be sure to disable legacy booting. You can also create installation media which only boot through UEFI. (I have an answer in my profile that shows you how.)
2. Avoid complex setups, no extended partitions (just change the partition table from dos/MBR to GPT) and no LVM unless you want to learn how to administer LVM (I don't).

I think questions like these where users mix up boot modes and accidentally remove Windows have been answered a few times before.